# Powershell - Need help passing the variables from one process to another

Tags: powershell, winforms

I'm trying to write a script that will create a very simple GUI with a dropdown list and a text box for input. I am using regions in the drop down list and then passing the selectedIndex to a process which assigns the hostname of the server for that region in nested if statements. If okay is selected it will then assign the hostname/printername based on the selected index and text input in the text box. If I write-host within the first process it gives me the correct hostname but it's not passing the string down the pipeline. Can anyone help?

```
# Create the logic for what happens when a list item is selected, and define the print server based on selected index.
$List.add_SelectedIndexChanged({
$Selected = $List.SelectedIndex
if ( 1 -eq $Selected )
{
($Server = 'serverName-1')
}
else
{
    if ( 2 -eq $Selected )
    {
    ($Server = 'serverName-2')
    }
    else
    {
        if ( 3 -eq $Selected )
        {
        ($Server = 'serverName-3')
        }
        else
        {
            if ( 4 -eq $Selected)
            { 
            ($Server = 'serverName-4')
            }
            else
            {
            ($Server = 'null')
            }
        }
    }
}
Write-Output $Server
})

#Process that happens after okay is pressed
if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
# I need to know why when I define $Server above, it isn't passing the data here.
$ServerName = $Server
$PrinterName = $textBox.Text
Add-Printer -ConnectionName \\$ServerName\$PrinterName
}
```

The outcome of this when run in Visual Studio Code with the Powershell addon installed is
\\printerName.

- Before adding `Write-Output $Server` I got an error about defined but unused variables so I wrote the output hoping to pass the data.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Correction: the outcome when run is \\\printerName showing that there is no data being passed for serverName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events execute in a different scope than your main form, you can however use a [reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/lang-spec/chapter-04?view=powershell-7.3#43-reference-types) such as a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/lang-spec/chapter-04?view=powershell-7.3#433-hashtables) to get a result from them in your script scope:

```bash
# this reference type is defined in the script scope
# it can be seen and updated from the event!
$ref = @{}

$List.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({
    $value = switch($List.SelectedIndex) {
        1 { 'serverName-1' }
        2 { 'serverName-2' }
        3 { 'serverName-3' }
        4 { 'serverName-4' }
        Default { 'null' }
    }

    # update the reference type variable outside this scope
    $ref['Server'] = $value
})

if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
    $ServerName  = $ref['Server'] # here you can reference outside variable
    $PrinterName = $textBox.Text
    Add-Printer -ConnectionName \\$ServerName\$PrinterName
}
```

Comment: Thank you Santiago!! This worked beautifully.